# Sato-Tate for length zero intervals

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve  (without CM) over a number field $K.$ Is it known that $a(\mathfrak{p})=N(\mathfrak{p})+1-|E(\mathbb{F}_{\mathfrak{p}})|$ is neither zero, not $2\sqrt{N(\mathfrak{p})}$ for almost all primes (in the sense of density) ? In literature I know, Sato-Tate holds for totally real number fields with some additional conditions on the elliptic curve. I am actually asking for this particular case of length zero, but for arbitrary number fields.

Comment: Of course $a(p)$ is never irrational, so your second sentence is equivalent to $a(p)$ is non-zero for almost all primes -- or I misunderstand something. For curves with complex multiplication that is very wrong and for the others it depends on what you mean by "almost all primes". Maybe you could improve the question.

Comment: Actually, yes assume E is without CM, and when we are looking over arbitary number fields, $a(\mathfrak{p})=N(\mathfrak{p})+1-|E(\mathbb{F}_{\mathfrak{p}})|$. I m asking for density of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $a(\mathfrak{p})$ is neither zero, nor $N(\mathfrak{p})^{1/2}$, and $\mathbb{F}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: I think it would be good to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: I just did, does it look good now ?

Comment: Yes, by the way https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115555/for-how-many-primes-does-an-elliptic-curve-over-a-totally-imaginary-field-have-s is related

Comment: The link actually answers my question generically for degree $2$ prime ideals. How about the degree $1$ case ? Also this shows an effective version generically. I wanted a much weaker (I only need zero density) result for a given non CM curve.