# Which quaternion algebras have class number one?

Tags: nt.number-theory, quaternions

Over Q, the definite quaternion algebras with a unique conjugacy class of maximal orders, i.e. "with class number one", are those with discriminant 2,3,5,7, and 13.

Three questions:

1. What is a reference for this result?
2. What are some examples of definite quaternions of class number one, over other totally real fields?
3. For a fixed real quadratic field, is there a known classification of definite quaternion algebras class number one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the first question, the statement goes back to Brzezinski (http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/JTNB/JTNB_1995__7_1/JTNB_1995__7_1_93_0/JTNB_1995__7_1_93_0.pdf), who treats all definite quaternion orders over $\mathbb{Z}$, not just maximal ones.  For maximal orders, this is an almost-immediate consequence of Eichler's mass formula.  The simplest proof I know of the mass formula follows in the same way as the proof of the analytic class number formula and can be found in his "Lectures on Modular Correspondences"; for prime discriminant this has many nice proofs ([Is there a nice proof of the fact that there are (p-1)/24 supersingular elliptic curves in characteristic p?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24573/is-there-a-nice-proof-of-the-fact-that-there-are-p-1-24-supersingular-elliptic)).

For the second and third questions, you can see my paper with Markus Kirschmer (http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/quatideal-fixed-errata-052613.pdf) where we find all Eichler orders of class number one: you're asking for Table 8.2.  Kirschmer and David Lorch are working on generalizing this in several directions.  The simplest (and arguably most beautiful) example is to take a maximal order in $B=(-1, -1 \mid \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}))$, the base change of the Hamilton quaternions to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.  Such a maximal order is unique up to conjugation in $B^\times$ and has unit group (modulo scalars) given by the rigid motions of the icosahedron (or dodecahedron); explicitly, it is generated as a $\mathbb{Z}[(\sqrt{5}+1)/2]$-algebra by $i$ and the element 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}i + j\right).$$

Answer (score 7):

It appears this is all done, mostly by students of Gabriele Nebe. see

http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/homes/Gabriele.Nebe/index.html.en

http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/homes/Markus.Kirschmer/orders/

and
http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/homes/Markus.Kirschmer/

and   http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/homes/David.Lorch/

The other name you should check is John Voight at Dartmouth.

http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/

Note that Voight is writing a book on quaternion algebras. You should read that.

Comment: I would say that John Voight is writing *The Book* on quaternion algebras.